# Twilio forward call to another Twilio number with custom parameters

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'd like to **forward** an ongoing Twilio call to a different Twilio Number and **pass along custom parameters**.

I was able to dial away using Twiml `<Dial>` + `<Number>` https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial but it's not possible to pass along custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass along custom parameters across the Public Switch Telephone Network (PSTN). It is not supported by that network.

What is the use case and how would the dialed party even be able to pull out those custom parameters?

Comment: Thank you Alan for explanation. So it seems the only solution how to transfer bits of data along the call is to use sendDigits https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits ?

Comment: sendDigits works after the dialed party answers, but it can be a way to convey information. You could also do a API call when the call comes in (maybe via CallerID or asking the party to enter some account code)  to try and match an incoming call with a specific record (so basically the information is out of band).

Comment: That's good idea as well. Thank you Alan!